# Can I package C# WPF with a C dll?

Tags: c, wpf, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I have a C# WPF that generates NuGet packages on Visual Studio 2019 Community.

The project needs to be packaged with a 32bit C .dll dependency that installs winusb drivers for a target device.  When attempting to add the reference:

[add dependency dll 'winusbLoader.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQty6.png)

I get the following error:

[The reference is invalid or supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcrRr.png)

When adding the reference manually to the .csproj script, Visual Studio shows broken reference warnings.

[libusbLoader broken reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf5bi.png)

My questions are:

1. Can only Console application reference C .dlls ?
2. How can it be possible to package a C .dll into a C# WPF?
3. Should I drop C# for a classical C++ GUI?

Thank you,

Comment: You don't add references to native assemblies from .NET apps. And you don't pack UI applications.

Comment: two way to go: user dllimport/dllexport, or use C++/CLR to create a bridge/interface for your c++ dll